# Why is EF one-to-one relationship deleting the parent upon adding of child?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have been working with Entity Framework for a while now using only one-to-many relationships with a code-first approach. However, I have now reached a point where I want to implement a one-to-zero/one relationship following the conventions here: [text](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx).

I created entities that follow this convention as far as I can tell, however, when I go to add objects to the tables after a successful migration, the parent object is added, then the child object is added, but when the child object is added, it deletes the parent object for seemingly no reason.

My entities are as follows:

```
[Table("Parents", Schema = "public")]
public class Parent
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public Child Child { get; set; }
}

[Table("Children", Schema = "public")]
public class Child
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
  public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

This creates the FK as expected. I did attempt to use model builder as well to handle this, but that results in a shadow state FK, since EF apparently knows that these entities are related without it being specified since it follows the convention I linked above.

For the sake of including it, here is the basic builder I attempted to use:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Parent> builder)
{
  builder.HasOne<Child>(b => b.Child).WithOne(b => b.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey<Child>(b => b.ParentId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Note that I also attempted this without the OnDelete behavior, so that is not the problem.

Finally, to add the objects, I am calling both repos, which share a base repo for adding, from a service layer. That base repo has an Add method:

```
public virtual int Add(TEntity entity, bool persist = true)
    {
        Table.Add(entity);
        return persist ? SaveChanges() : 0;
    }
```

and the SaveChanges method which utilized the context passed:

```
public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This is the same base repo I use throughout many other one-to-many relationships, and have had no difficulty with it, making me look to the configuration as the primary suspect.

Thank you for any input and let me know if you need any clarifications.

EDIT FOR CLARITY:
I only have one database context that all the entities are in. By repository, I was referring to the file that actually accesses the entities, and I have one class for accessing each individual entity.

Comment: The mention of "both repositories"  is a bit of a concern. When adding a parent with new children you only need to "Add" the parent where the child will be inserted automatically. If you start adding with references to existing entities or changing references around then you can start getting odd behaviour as associations get dropped and entities can end up getting orphaned or deleted. Can you add the code where you are calling the Add etc. for the parent and/or child?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As for the multiple repositories, the pattern being followed is as shown in the diagram of this post: https://pmichaels.net/service-repository-pattern/ where a service layer has access to multiple repositories. My understanding is that business logic may require access to multiple repositories and I have implemented one repository per entity, so if I wanted to request just a Child, I don't have to go through the Parent to do so. However, I decided that the Parent and Child which I was working with really could be combined into a single entity with proper DTOs in place

Answer (score 1):

That example (https://pmichaels.net/service-repository-pattern/) follows a more traditional ADO-type pattern where the repository is managing the database connection, SQL generation, and returning a DTO. It is also only a Pseudo example not real-world code given what exactly is "DB" and the return type of "RunSql".

Entity Framework and it's `DbContext` and `DbSet` already serve the purposes outlined by this discussion piece so wrapping an additional repository across it, especially at a per-entity level is not recommended. To put it in context, A `DbContext` instance represents a unit of work across multiple `DbSet` instances that represent repositories for individual tables, represented by entities. Introducing a repository pattern per entity amounts to introducing a wrapper around the Unit of Work (DbContext) scoped to a single DbContext.

In a nutshell, just don't do it. Does EF require a Repository pattern or Unit of Work pattern on top of it?  No. It serves both of these purposes inherently. Are there reasons to use an explicit Unit of Work and Repository pattern around EF? Yes. Two good reasons I do use a UoW + Repository pattern with EF is to make unit testing code that works with Entities easier, and so that repositories can serve as a place to centralize lower-level, common domain rules or actions like Authorization checks and multi-tenancy concerns. (One database, many separate consumers)

Going back to Paul Michael's example, you will note that right at the start he outlines one repository per service with the ability to share repositories between services. Personally I promote the use of thinking of the single responsibility of a Repository to be the Service it serves, not probing into an individual entity leaving services needing to juggle multiple repositories and then somehow handling the unit of work concerns, like ensuring operations made by several repositories are committed or rolled back together. So in an MVC example where I have an OrderController, I would have it serviced by an OrderRepository. This isn't a `Repository<Order>`, but rather a repository that will serve all needs of the OrderController actions. That will be doing things like constructing new orders, while resolving any associated references for navigation properties from relevant DbSets, retrieving lists of related details for Ajax calls like Product lists, etc. Yes, this means multiple repositories could reference the same DbSets like "Products" but their Single Responsibility is serving the needs of their Service/Controller. What I don't want to do is have every Controller referencing an OrderRpository, CustomerRepository, ProductRepository, OrderLineRepository, DeliveryInstructionRepository, etc. etc. etc. This is potentially a LOT of dependencies to juggle around, making it a lot of work to mock out when I want to unit test my controller. A Repository can help centralize core rules like authorization, having a dependency to resolve what user is currently logged in and what permissions they have, helping secure actions (like whether they are allowed to delete or update rows) and filtering what data they might be able to retrieve. When it comes to Entity Framework, I want to preserve as much capability as I can when it comes to things like leveraging navigation properties, projection, and late query execution. This is often overlooked or deliberately sacrificed when using Repositories per-entity, or for purposes such as to abstract the fact that the domain layer is using Entity Framework.

Looking deeper into a per-Entity Repository such as with Generics (`Repository<TEntity>`) you start running into all kinds of limitations and complexities. What if you want to eager load some related properties when you fetch data? What if you want to project data down to a simpler, smaller summary view for things like search results? What if you want to introduce pagination? Sorting? Suddenly it doesn't look so practical to abstract and isolate so much with a repository over EF's `DbContext`/`DbSet`. These are extremely powerful classes through their `IQueryable` implementation, so attempting to wrap and hide them is putting your domain in a straightjacket.

Services can share common Repositories where it makes sense that a Repository can serve some truly common info. An example of this might be something like a ContentRepository that can can serve localized content used for constructing views. I don't need the same code in virtually every other repository, so I can easily justify every controller having their {Controller}Repository and a ContentRepository dependency rather than having the same GetContent(contentId) method in every repository... Or something like GetContent(contentId) can be a method in a base class.

That should hopefully give you something to think about when it comes to designing around EF and whether it is worth using a Repository pattern. Most projects, especially when developers are starting out with EF, I would recommend not using a Repository pattern. Again, the Repository can be useful, but it needs to be justified. Enabling unit testing and centralizing very core, universal filters/behavior are two good reasons I can offer. Abstracting Entity Framework, interpreting the Single Responsibility Principle to be at the entity level, or obsessing over DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) are reasons I would caution against.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it definitely helps look at different strategies for setting up a structure. I will edit my post to reflect that by repositories, I meant repository access layers. The entities are all in a single DbContext, but I split access to each entity up into files which I have been calling "[Class]Repo". Definitely a lot to chew on here though!